# Normalization of vectors to compare distance.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, machine-learning, standard-deviation

Let's say I have a set of vectors and I want to find the minimum distance between one of them and the rest. **EDIT**: This is a Machine Learning task in which I'm missing values in my data and am looking for the vectors most "similar" to the ones with missing values in order to fill those up with the values of the most similar vector.

My thought is immediately to compute the Euclidian distances in $n$ dimensions between that one vector (with missing value(s)) and all the others in pairs and take the minimum of those results.
However, someone pointed out to me that I would have to "normalize" my vectors so that my calculations wouldn't be biased by the different units and scales of the independent variables (components of the vectors in this case), in other words so that an independent variable with a much wider range of values wouldn't potentially weigh much more than another in the distance calculation.

He recommended taking the standard deviation of the row vectors (SD for each component across all vectors) and dividing the corresponding complnent of each vector by that values, as well as subtracting the mean of each component across all vectors and subtracting it, so that each component across all vectors would be scaled by $\frac{1}{SD}$ and $(-)mean$.

**My question is**: Is standardizing really important in this case, does that justification make sense? And if it does, why and what is the best way of doing it (and why again)? And what is really the effect of standardizing in this way? Does everything come out to have the same range?

Comment: It would help to give more detail about what you will do once you have the distance. If you just want to know which of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is closest to $v_0$ then no normalization is needed. However if (for example) you have another set of vectors $w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and you want to compare distances between the sets, then it might matter.

Comment: @stewbasic, yes, I just need to know which vector in a set of vectors is closest to a given vector in the same set. However, those vectors are really lists of features (one per component) and the justification I was given is that if you want to find out which vector is the closest to another in terms of overall features, you cannot let the scale and units of a certain feature have more weight than another. For example if you have height in inches and some other measure in millimeters, the difference in the millimeter dimension might weigh a lot more than the difference in the height dimension.

Comment: Ah, in that case some normalization makes sense. Put another way, there are many ways to define distance between your vectors, and Euclidean is probably not a good choice if the different components are incomparable. Imagine the components are (height in m, weight in kg) of a person. Then Euclidean distance puts (2,70) closer to (3,70) than (2,72).

Comment: @stewbasic, right that makes sense. I guess what I'm wondering is how we come up with the standardizing schemes we come up with? They seem arbitrary to me? Do we choose features (components) to have the same range of values? Is that really more "fair"? Why not some other scheme?

Comment: It sounds like you are implementing nearest neighbor classification? I suspect it's difficult to give an answer that applies in all cases. However maybe someone with more expertise can give a better answer. I suggest adding the machine-learning tag to your question and explicitly noting in your question that the components of the vectors are feature values.

Comment: @stewbasic, thank you I just did that. It's actually a little more complicated; I have missing values in my data and am trying to approximate those values by finding the vectors most "similar" to the one with missing values and filling those up with the same values as the most similar vector has.